# Which datatype is behind tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading or how is this build up?

Tags: c#

I'm new to `C#` and now I saw this piece of code

```
tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading
```

Which datatype could be behind that? It is used like an array and also dot notation is used. Is `tableItems` a separate object/class? Or is it build up with a `Dictionary` or `List`? I only have an [excerpt](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_3_-_customizing_a_table%27s_appearance/) and not access to the full source code ...

I want to build the same for my application. How can I do this?

**Edit:**

I'm interested into the `tableItems[1].Heading` part (without indexPath.Row). I know that I get downvoted for that but I'm interested into the solution. Downvote me and provide the solution.

Comment: Have a look at the declaration of `tableItems` or look at intellisense/debugger. Actually it can be any type since you can create an [indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(v=vs.71).aspx) easily.

Comment: Try to figure out the type of `tableItems`.

Comment: I've added the link but there is no information about that.

Comment: Most likely a [`UITableView`](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/populate_a_table/) then.

Comment: @knittl: It's not a `UITableView`. In the linked example you posted it is an array of `string` but that was the simple variant. I'm looking for the more advanced one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/storyboard_a_tableview/):

*TableItem.cs*

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Storyboard {
    public class TableItem {
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        public string SubHeading { get; set; }

        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        public string Url {get;set;}

        public UITableViewCellStyle CellStyle
        {
            get { return cellStyle; }
            set { cellStyle = value; }
        }
        protected UITableViewCellStyle cellStyle = UITableViewCellStyle.Default;

        public UITableViewCellAccessory CellAccessory
        {
            get { return cellAccessory; }
            set { cellAccessory = value; }
        }
        protected UITableViewCellAccessory cellAccessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;

        public TableItem () { }

        public TableItem (string heading)
        { Heading = heading; }
    }
}
```

*Filling with data*

```
List<TableItem> tableItems = new List<TableItem>();

tableItems.Add (new TableItem("Vegetables") { SubHeading="65 items", ImageName="Vegetables.jpg", Url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leaf_vegetables"});
```

*Usage*

```
detail.Title = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading;
```

So it's basically a `List` with a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially the same as:

```
int index = indexPath.Row;
var row = tableItems[index];
... row.Heading;
```

Don't (and cannot) know the exact types. But `tableItems` is most likely a `Dictionary<int, SomeClass>` (or any type implementing an indexer property). `SomeClass` provides a property `Heading`.

---

To build it yourself:

```
class IndexPath {
  public int Row { get; set; }

  public IndexPath(int row) { this.Row = row; }
}

class Row {
  public Heading Heading { get; set; }

  public Row(Heading heading) { this.Heading = heading; }
}

class Heading {
}

var tableItems = new Dictionary<int, Row>();
tableItems.Add(0, new Row(new Heading());
tableItems.Add(1, new Row(new Heading());
// ... and so on

var indexPath = new IndexPath(1);
tableItems[indexPath.Row].Heading;
```

Comment: I'm not interested in `indexPath.Row` because it could be any number. I'm looking into `tableItems[1].Heading`. As I can see from your approach you are using a `Dictionary` together with a custom class?

Comment: Yes I am (using a dictionary with custom class). But in fact it can be any type which implements a custom indexer (`public CustomClass this[int idx] { get { return ....; }`). There's nothing special about that.

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dk1507sz.aspx). - or better yet, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).